# What do IO Error and Stream Error mean (Flash)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, actionscript-3, ioerror

I'm trying to do an http post from flash on my website to a method in a controller (My site is on Asp.Net MVC) and I'm getting this error:

Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://www.mysite.com/Home/DoSomething
    at Main/postToMyWebsite()

Any ideas of why these errors happen and how to prevent them?

Please let me know if you require any more info

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: To help you narrow this down, I'd suggest trying the following: Run your ASP.NET site in debug mode and set a breakpoint in your controller method.  If the breakpoint is reached, then you can step through the code until an exception is reached.  If the breakpoint isn't reached, then your URL or request method may be incorrect.  Also, take a look at the Application event log for ASP.NET warnings.  That can help you find answers on the server side.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest that you post your ActionScript that's doing the post as well as your .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link

http://curtismorley.com/2008/02/08/actionscript-error-2032/

These types of error you can expect when the wrong URL is used!!!!.

Comment: I've read that post. What if I know it's the right url... any ideas?
I thought it might have something to do with the fact that it's asp.net mvc, is there any specific way you need to have the url to do a post to an mvc method?

Answer (score 0):

Does your POST work, if made from a standard HTML form? If not, I wouldn't expect it to work in Flash, so you'll have to check your ASP code.

Does the ASP page echo anything? You could be getting an error if there are no headers or no output at all from that page. Try to output something.

Also, it might help to listen to the `httpStatus` events. That might give you some insight on what's going on. To add a `httpStatus` listener, you do something like:

```
myUrlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
    trace("HTTP status recieved: " + event.status);
}
```

Please post the code if none of theese work. It's quite hard to guess what could be going on there..